# Why is the energy density of 26650 Li-ion cells lower than that of 18650 cells?

Tags: batteries

I have an application where I need a rechargeable battery in a very tight space too small for two 18650’s but large enough for a single 26650 cell. I have done some research on these cells and currently the highest capacity commercial 18650 cells are pushing [3500mAh’s](https://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Keeppower%2018650%203500mAh%20P1835U%20(Blue-white)%202017%20UK.html) [(and here)](https://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Samsung%20INR18650-35E%203500mAh%20(Pink)%20UK.html). Since the 26650 cells have a little over twice the volume as an 18650, I expected the capacities to scale proportionally, but the highest capacity commercial cells are a little over [5500mAh](https://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Shockli%20IMR26650%205500mAh%20(Black)%202017%20UK.html). Why are these high cap cells not closer to 7000mAh?

Comment: Could you post datasheets for the batteries in question? You need to make sure that discharge characteristics are specified under comparable conditions.

Comment: @Ale..chenski just added some legitimate tests. FYI, there are several 18650’s that are near 3500mAh, but I just included one. The guy who runs this website is well known amongst the battery community and reputable

Comment: I did some calculation, since I though this was a mistake. It is not. 26650 offers 34 MJ/m3 and 18650 has 42 MJ/m3... Both similar protected keeppower cells. My best guess is the more surface area foil in the battery also increases losses to the terminals. But I now I really want to know!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we just compare the two cells you linked, there is an obvious difference: The 18650 is rated for 5A continuous discharge while the (twice as big) 26650 is rated for 20 A - four times more. 
The size of a battery is not only determined by capacity (energy density), but also by its current output (power density). The inner structure has to be built in a more massive way if you want to draw a high current from the battery which requires a low internal resistance.

If you check typical applications for these batteries the large 26650 is normally not used in applications that are designed for long running time but rather in those using a lot of power like high-end flashlights.

Comment: Maybe the provided link was a bad example because of the included protection circuit. I added one more without a protection circuit, but your answer about the current draw still holds

Comment: Basically there are two kinds of lithium ion batteries. High discharge batteries (used in power tools and small EV's that don't have a lot of range, etc) and low discharge batteries (such as are used in laptops). The 18650s with 3.4 and 3.5 Ah capacity are laptop cells. If you look at high discharge cells, you will find that 2.5 Ah is more common, and 3 Ah is about the state of the art right now. I am not writing this as an answer because it is just an elaboration on asdfex's answer.

Comment: @mkeith There are more than two kinds.  Six chemistries.  If you are looking only at power (discharge rate)  and capacity there are four combinations.  But the issue here is energy.  Less energy sometimes needs a bigger package.  So if you add energy into the mix then there are more combinations.  There there is lifespan (charge cycles) to consider.  The lower capacity LCO (1.5-2.5Ah) is common becasue it has been around 30 years.  The higher capacity NMC has been around about 10 years.  Laptops (low power) use is mostly old cheap LCO in bigger packages (e.g Li-po) than 18650.

Comment: @Misunderstood - this answer and comment is not about chemistry. For each application there is a chemistry better suited than another, but the issue of energy density versus power density exists even when using the same chemistry.

Comment: Energy density is much greater between chemistries than within the same chemistry.  The question was between 18650 and 26650 which in the majority of the cases are indeed different chemistries. When a 18650 has more energy than a  26650 it is obviously different chemistries.  It certainly is not about the "massive way" the battery is built, it is definitely different chemistry.  It's the chemistry that allows more or less power, energy, and capacity.  I have seen may high end flashlights, never seen one that uses a 26650 battery.   Flashlights run well with 18650 LCO and power tools use LMO.

Comment: There are different ways to categorize cells. By size, by detailed chemistry, by manufacturer, etc. I choose to categorize them by whether they are intended for high discharge applications or not. It is an easy dividing line, because high discharge cells are rated for 15 Amps and more. But laptop cells are rated for, say, 4A and less. I don't see any 8A or 10A rated 18650s on the market.

Comment: @mkeith You live a sheltered life. $6, 18650, 3000 mAh, continuous 20 Amp.  https://www.18650batterystore.com/18650-p/lg-hg2.htm  This is an NMC mixed with LMO to get the balanced performance.  NMC batteries are often packaged in an 18650 cell and have high power (discharge) and decent capacity.   NMC and LMO mixed chemistries are very common.

Comment: That example does not contradict what I said. Everything is either 20 Amps or 4 Amps with almost nothing in between. That is what I said.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are these high cap cells not closer to 7000mAh?

Because they are not "high cap", just bigger in physical size.
In order to have high power (i.e. high discharge) you have to have the correct Li-ion chemistry which, today, would be Lithium Nickel Manganese (NMC).  NMC is a low energy chemistry.

**It's the chemistry.**

Not all Li-ion are the same.  There are a variety of Li-ion chemistries.  The lower energy chemistries are more likely to found in larger packages.

Notice the division between chemistries and cell size is at about 150 Whr/kg energy density. With lower energy a bigger cell is required for what a consumer expects to be a reasonable time between charges.

**26650**
A 26650 Li-ion battery is typically a

- LMO, 3.7V Li-manganese LiMn<sub>2</sub>O<sub>4</sub> High power, less capacity, energy=100–150Wh/kg used in power tools.  Varied packaging.
- LFP, 3.2V Li-phosphate (LiFePO<sub>4</sub>) with high power (high discharge) but low capacity, high currents and endurance, energy=90–120Wh/kg  Beginning to be used as a replacement for lead acid starter and deep cycle.

---

**18650**

A 3.6V 18650 Li-ion can be either

- NMC, Lithium Nickel Manganese (LiNiMnCoO<sub>2</sub>) High capacity and
  high power, energy=150–220Wh/kg
- LCO, Li-cobalt (LiCoC<sub>2</sub>)  High energy, limited power. energy=150–200Wh/kg
- NCA, Li-aluminum (LiNiCoAlO<sub>2</sub>) Highest capacity with moderate power. energy=200-260Wh/kg

---

The above are not hard rules but typical of what is found in the market.  There are also batteries that use mixed chemistries.  NMC and LMO are often combined to balance capacity and power in a 18650 cell.

---

For more on Li-ion chemistry see: [Types of Lithium-ion](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/types_of_lithium_ion)

---

It gets confusing when there are so many charlatans in the battery business. It just gets worse and worse as they try to one up each other with new and bigger lies.
You will find that most 3.7V Li-ion are actually 3.6V in the datasheet.  It's the charlatan vendors. Technically only Li-manganese (LMO & NMC) cells are 3.7V.

---

> Since the 26650 cells have a little over twice the volume as an 18650,
>   I expected the capacities to scale proportionally,

The 18650 LCO cell has been around for 30 years so it is the preferred cell size.  If you want more capacity or power you wire then in parallel. In the past 10 years newer chemistries have been developed like NMC. NMC and LMO manganese are lower capacity and were more commonly proprietary packaged and high priced.  Look at the price of power tool replacement batteries at Home Depot, $100+.  To meet consumer run time expectations lower capacity chemistries are packaged in larger cells such as 26650.

As 26650 get used in more consumer products you will see some very high capacity 26650 NMC cells. As the patents begin to run out you will see more licensing deals which will raise market share for NMC.

Patents should be running out an Panasonic's NCA  Li-aluminum chemistry.  A lot of R&D is currently focused on this highest capacity NCA.  Tesla is pushing for it.

[Tesla's NMC and NCA Batteries](http://fortune.com/2015/05/18/tesla-grid-batteries-chemistry/)

Comment: The OP has added a link to the cell under discussion. It is not a LiFEPO4 cell. Nominal voltage is listed as 3.7V, but it appears to be a high-discharge type of cell.

Comment: @mkeith yes that would be a Li-manganese, high power, less capacity.  High power = high discharge.  And it was a 26650 cell I presume.  It makes sense that a lower capacity chemistry would be packaged in a larger sized cell.  If you look at the two I listed, commonly found in a 26650 format, have the lowest energy (Wh).  They both also have high power (discharge rate).